# Make the T in generic function inherit from something

Tags: c#, oop, generics

Not sure if the description is clear, I'll explain by example:

```
    class A
    {
       int x;
    }

    class B : A { }
    
    void Something<T where T:A>(T item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.x);
    }
```

The

> T where T:A

is not a valid syntax. I want to achieve the same thing. It's possible in that way in class/interface declerations. Is there an alternative here also?

Comment: `void Something<T>(T item) where T:A`

Comment: Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint

Answer (score 0):

just change the syntax

```
void Something<T>(T item) where T:A 
{
    .....
}
```